# Matching up information on Excel from 2 different sheets

Tags: excel

In the next step of the analysis I'm currently working on I have one sheet with two important columns. Column A specifies gene name and Column B specifies a number I am interested in (first screenshot). Then, I have a second sheet that repeats Column A but the gene name entries are in a different order to the first sheet and a Column B which has a lettered classification system (A-Z) which gives me some detail regarding the function of that gene. I would like to match the Column A and Column B data from sheet 1 to the Column B data from sheet 2 but as the column A in both sheets is the same but in a different order, is there a way to get Excel to match the correct letter in the second sheet to the correct gene name and number in the first sheet? The screenshots are of fake test data just to help me clarify this text! Any help really appreciated. [image][image]

Comment: Screenshot 1 is sheet 1 and screenshot 2 is sheet 2.

Comment: I would suggest looking into [index match](https://www.excel-easy.com/examples/index-match.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Index/Match()` like below-

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!$B$2:$B$20,MATCH(A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$A$20,0))
```

`VLOOKUP()` will also work

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$B$20,2,FALSE)
```

If you have <kbd>Excel365</kbd> then use `XLOOKUP()` function.

```
=XLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$A$20,Sheet2!$B$2:$B$20,"Not Found")
```